# Getting Errors In C Key Press Checker Code

Tags: c++

I am getting these errors when I run my code in Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 and yes, I'm a beginner
My program is a basic test program designed to give an int value on Left Shifts' Key Press.

In function `int main()':`
Do' undeclared (first use this function) 
(Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.) 
`;' before '{' token 
'While' undeclared (first use this function)`
;' before "on"

And here's my code:

```
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int on;
    on = 1;
    Do
    {
            GetASyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT int key);
            cout << key << endl;
    } 
            While on = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do I begin? Please learn C++ to a good extent **before** exploring the Windows API. You'll probably take less time preventing the errors than you will just writing winapi code and fixing them, and definitely come out of it with a lower blood pressure.

Comment: And sorry, but what exactly do you want to accomplish? What kind of int value do you want? The vk code? An arbitrary value assigned when the key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do/While should be do/while (i.e. lower case). It is a good idea to learn about/read the error and warning messages generated by the compiler.

Comment: Typoed function (though I don't expect that if you don't use the Windows API) and weird call as well, along with missing parentheses around the condition and the wrong number of equals signs. There's a decent possibility of missing includes also.